# Hyperlink going to old version of the link

Tags: excel, vba, hyperlink

I've a Hyperlink formula that creates a Google Maps link based on a list of Post Codes:

```
=IFERROR(HYPERLINK((SUBSTITUTE(TEXTJOIN("/",1,"https://www.google.co.uk/maps/dir",INDIRECT("B"&INDEX(Table6121415[Row],MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(Table6121415[Row]<>"",0),0))&":B"&LOOKUP(TRUE,""<>Table6121415[Row],Table6121415[Row])))," ","+"))),"")
```

When I click on it, it sends me to the previous version of the link, before I updated the postcodes.

The only workaround I found is to copy, paste values into a different cell, then F2 into the cell, and press enter, then click on the newly pasted link.

It would be great if I could just click the link, but failing that, I've been trying to make my workaround into a macro.

The press enter part of the process translates into the macro as typing in the new link. Which is therefore a static link, and the same link every time.

The macro ends up like this.

```vb
Range("P2").Select
Selection.Copy
Range("P3").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Application.CutCopyMode = False
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _      "https://www.google.co.uk/maps/dir/DE65+???/DE1???/DE1???/DE22???/DE65+???/DE3+???/DE65+???/DE22???/DE24???/DE24???/DE23???/DE23???/DE65+???"
Range("P3").Select
Selection.Hyperlinks(1).Follow NewWindow:=False, AddHistory:=True
```

If I take out the `ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1` line, it ends up with the same result as before.

Sample data:
It's a list of postcodes. Today's list, for example:
DE65 5?? DE13 0?? DE65 5?? DE65 5?? DE13 0?? DE15 9?? DE13 0?? DE65 5?? DE3 9?? DE65 5?? DE13 0?? DE65 5?? DE15 9?? DE65 5??

Everything in the Indirect is only there to make sure it selects the rows for today's date, but the formula can be simplified to this:

```
=IFERROR(HYPERLINK((SUBSTITUTE(TEXTJOIN("/",1,"google.co.uk/maps/dir",B1075:B1088)," ","+"))),"") The range B1075:B1088 is what I make dynamic with the Indirect, Lookup, Match. But either way, it still causes the same issue.
```

Comment: Are you trying to add a link to each row of a table (only if that row is not blank)? Is the link one of the columns in the table, or outside of it? Do the lat/long columns in the table have headers?

Comment: Hi Peter, no, it's just one random cell that the link is created in.

Basiclaly I have an infinti elist that I add next days appontments to, the formula then finds any rows that are dated as tomorrow, and takes the post codes in the Post Code column, and stictches them together into a Google Maps URL. So it changes every day.

It all works, but only if I copy, paste values, F2, Enter, every time.

If I could get the link to work without that procdess, I'd make it into a clikcable button, but for now it just sits messily off to one side of my spreadsheet.

Comment: Do you have a sample of the data that goes with the formula?

Comment: It's literally just a list of postcodes. This is today's list, for example:
DE65 5??
DE13 0??
DE65 5??
DE65 5??
DE13 0??
DE15 9??
DE13 0??
DE65 5??
DE3 9??
DE65 5??
DE13 0??
DE65 5??
DE15 9??
DE65 5??

Everything in the Indirect is only there to make sure it selects the rows for today's date, but the formula can be simplified to this: 

=IFERROR(HYPERLINK((SUBSTITUTE(TEXTJOIN("/",1,"https://www.google.co.uk/maps/dir",B1075:B1088)," ","+"))),"")

The range B1075:B1088 is what I make dynamic with the Indirect, Lookup, Match. But either way, it still causes the same issue.